# Desktop Sharing without installing software

Tags: java, desktop, sharing

Helo ,

I want to create desktop sharing solution  , without having the user to download any software .

Can java help ? I have seen such a solution so I know it for sure that desktop sharing without downloading software via browser is possible .

I am not sure how to achieve it .

Does any one know ?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this on client side. This means that you have to create thin client that shows screen of remote machine, catches keyboard and mouth events and passes them to other side. If you wish to complete the task without downloading solution on server side you can use existing software already supported by targeted OS. For example remote desktop for Windows or XWindow remoting for Unix systems.

So, architecture of system you are dreaming about will look like the following.

- Server that creates remote desktop connections to target machines.
- Web front-end that delivers the screenshots from the remote desktop to client's browser, catches events, brings them back and emulate user's behavior for the remote desktop session.

Please pay attention that if you wish to create something that will really work, e.g. be responsive enough, support many concurrent connections etc you need at least 5 developers for at least 1 year (full time). After a year you will get solution similar to LogMeIn but worse (I mean quality).

Anyway I wish you good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all OS's support this out of the box.  Windows and Mac with Remote Desktop, Linux with X server